# WooCommerce checkout page price break down table hook

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I want to add a new price break down line to the WooCommerce breakdown page. I've looked at using these hooks which supposedly should allow me to post to the table.

```
woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents
woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping
woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents
```

However, if I echo a string as a test it always appears above the checkout table price break down.

Is there any way to add a new line item to the WooCommerce checkout table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the hooks you're looking for are going to be either `woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping` or `woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total`.  If you need to get in between where those two put you then you're looking at modifying a template, which isn't as future proof but is still a viable option when the hooks aren't enough.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to use an override.